# Search datas in select

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I have a large database of client data, and I need to find an easier way to select this data. I try use this code, but for some reason I can't "filter" the data. Thanks for your help.

```
function trocaOpcao(valor, objSel) {
    for (i=0; i < objSel.length; i++){
        qtd = valor.length;
        if (objSel.options[i].text.substring(0, qtd).toUpperCase() == valor.toUpperCase()) {
            objSel.selectedIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

```
<fieldset id="iLocal">
    <input type="text" name="nLocalizar" id="iLocalizar" placeholder="Digite o controle que deseja pesquisar" onkeyup="trocaOpcao(this.value, document.form.nId);">
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="Prop2">
    <legend class="legend">Localizar</legend>
    Localizar:
    <select name="nId" id= "iId" class="nNamesel" onchange="Alterar(this.value)">
        <option value="0" disabled selected>Selecione o Proprietário</option>
        <?php
            $result_nome="SELECT * FROM teste ORDER BY proprietario";
            $resultado=mysqli_query($conexao,$result_nome);
            while($row_resultado=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){ 
        ?>
        <option id="iOpt" value="<?php echo $row_resultado['id'];?>">
            <?php 
                echo utf8_encode( $row_resultado['id']." - ".$row_resultado['proprietario']." / ".$row_resultado['logradouro']) 
            ?>
        </option>
        <?php
            }
        ?>

    </select></br></br>
</fieldset>
```

I want to enter the id in the input and show these id in select with the client data, so when I click in the select I'll easily find what I want..

P.S = When I tried to do this in a diferent page, it worked perfectly

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help topic [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Good questions normally have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, StackOverflow has an [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with lots of information. Also please take special attention that what you're writing has gramatically correct english. Thanks.

Comment: Entendi, é meu primeiro post aqui ainda... Estou entendendo aos poucos como funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. I removed PHP code that it's not relevant to the answer.

```js
function trocaOpcao(valor, objName) {
    var objSel = document.querySelector('[name=' + objName + ']');
    for (i=0; i < objSel.length; i++){
        if ( objSel.options[i].text
               .toUpperCase()
               .indexOf(valor.toUpperCase()) != -1 ) {
            objSel.selectedIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset id="iLocal">
      <input type="text" name="nLocalizar" id="iLocalizar" placeholder="Digite o controle que deseja pesquisar" onkeyup="trocaOpcao(this.value, 'nId');">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="Prop2">
      <legend class="legend">Localizar</legend>
      Localizar:
      <select name="nId" id="iId" class="nNamesel" onchange="">
         <option value="0" disabled selected>Selecione o Proprietário</option>
         <option id="iOpt" value="1">1-Fulano-local1</option>
         <option id="iOpt" value="2">2-Beltrano-local2</option>
         <option id="iOpt" value="3">3-Sicrano-local3</option>      </select>
     </br></br>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Please understand with this solution you can put anything you want in the input. Not just the value. Example: try to enter: "belt".

Comment: Obrigado pela Ajuda! E obrigado pelo mimo também kkkkk, o código funcionou perfeitamente no meu caso.